# Can the content attribute of <meta name="robots" /> be left empty?

Tags: meta-tags, meta-robots

Is

```
<meta name="robots" content="" />
```

a legitimate `meta`, exactly equivalent to:

1. `<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />`
2. `<meta name="robots" content="all" />`
3. *[nothing]*

Or *must* the `content` attribute contain explicit directives?

Comment: Whatever the answer is, I am concluding from reading multiple sources that option _3. Nothing_ is by far the best approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> option 3. *Nothing* is by far the best approach.

If you mean that the robots tag should be omitted entirely, then yes, that would be the best option if you want the page to be indexed and followed.

The other options just add superfluous bytes and will be *ignored*.

As mentioned in [my answer to your other related question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/111330/52912), Google only includes `all` (out of what you have posted) in its list of valid directives. But as Google states, "this has no effect" anyway, as this is the *default value*. Google (and I suspect *all* search engine bots) simply ignore `index, follow` - since this is again the default behavior.

> ```
> <meta name="robots" content="" />
> ```

An *empty* `content` attribute is valid HTML. However, it contains no directive, so can only be ignored (as stated above).

Comment: Thanks @DocRoot. The reason behind my question is that I was thinking in terms of PHP-templating. Initially, compared to providing a zero-length string variable (`''`) for the directives, it seemed excessive to require a condition checking whether the template should include the robots meta or not. But I am happily reconciled with that now.